B&W 1930s British film - two couples live together in country house as trial marriage
This an old movie, a comedy.  It's about a wealthy playboy who's interested in a nice girl.  Also, a broke man wants to marry a wealthy but nasty woman.  They all meet at a party.  The nasty lady says she'll marry the broke man if he'll live with her in her country house as a "trial marriage."  Both couples go to the house )I think it's in Scotland).  The servants are all shocked at the immorality and quit.  The people have no idea how to cook or clean or take care of themselves. There is a big storm, and they run out of food.  One of the men accidentally winds up in a woman's bedroom, and there's a big misunderstanding and fight.  The playboy sets off in a boat in the storm to get food, or to just leave or something.  The broke man and the nice girl hit it off, and get engaged when they realize they're both nice people who can actually do some work and solve problems.  The playboy is stuck marrying the nasty lady.


On Approval (1944)
Based on a 1926 play by Frederick Lonsdale, this was English actor Clive Brook’s only directorial effort. Sure the release date's off by a decade, but I'm fairly certain this is the film you saw.

The main story follows two impoverished gentlemen, George, the 10th
  Duke of Bristol and his friend Richard Halton, and their efforts to
  marry into money, namely wealthy, 41-year-old widow Maria Wislack and
  her much younger American friend, Helen Hale.

 

After a party at George's town house, Maria suggests to Richard, that
  she should take him away for a month ''on approval'' to her Scottish
  island home. They will spend the days together and each night Richard
  will row across the lake to the mainland inn. If the two are
  compatible, they will marry.

The following section covers another plot point you mentioned:

George and Helen decide to join the group, but on reaching Scotland
  they find the local hotel fully booked; then, since all must live at
  Maria's home, the prudish servants quit.

 
How the rest of the movie plays out:

As the days pass, each sees the other for what he or she really is:
  Helen tells George to marry Maria, who is as selfish as he; Richard
  discovers he cannot stand Maria. Richard and Helen decide to leave the
  island together secretly when Helen finds herself attracted to him.
  After a nightmare-riddden night, Helen and Richard return to the
  island to confront George and Maria; the sound of the wedding march
  drowns out the arguing of the four, and in response to a question form
  the narrator, Helen admits that she has married Richard.

Watch a short clip; the full movie has also been uploaded online.
~ Synopsis edited from DVDtalk, allmovie and Fifty Classic British Films, 1932-1982: A Pictorial Record. 
